# Как в запросе к dbf указать кодировку?

Tags: c#, dbf

Есть dbf файл, созданный Visual Fox Pro. Его я менять не могу, могу только читать. Читаю

```
 conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=e:\\;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=;Password=;";
                    conn.Open();
                    OleDbCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
                    comm.CommandText = @"SELECT NOMER, FEMGN, FEOBS, DATA, TIME FROM ANALIZ";
                    dt.Load(comm.ExecuteReader());
                    column = dt.Columns[0];
                    row = dt.Rows[0];
                    result = row[column].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Но в файле кодировка dos. Необходимо привести к utf -8. Пытаюсь так - не получается

```
 var fromEncodind = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);//из какой кодировки
                var bytes = fromEncodind.GetBytes(o);
                var toEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;//в какую кодировку
              string  ans = toEncoding.GetString(bytes);
```

Видимо из базы уже получаю корявую строку. Подскажите как в запросе к dbf указать кодировку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DBF таблицы с кодировкой 866 грузится нормально, если загружать через [OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro 9.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839)

```
private void LoadTable(string path, DataGridView dataGrid)
    {
        try
        {
            var connectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=" + path + ";Collating Sequence=MACHINE";
            var con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
            var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path), con);
            con.Close();
            var dataSet = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);
            dataGrid.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];                
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message + " " + path, "Ошибка открытия DBF таблицы", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);                
        }
    }
```

Comment: Подскажите как сделать запрос по все полям в E:\ANALIZ.DBF. а то мне пишет ошибку + Сообщение об исключении = "Поставщик не смог определить значение Decimal. Например, строка только что была создана, значение по умолчанию для столбца Decimal не было доступно, а потребитель еще не задал нового значения Decimal.", Тип исключения = "System.InvalidOperationException"

Answer (score 1):

помимо Provider=VFPOLEDB.1 из [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/312648/8566) Мурада, в случае английской винды еще потребуется:

```
var value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1];

string encodedValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString((Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding(866),
                      Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value.ToString()))));
```

Comment: Вместо слов "предыдущий ответ" лучше указать, чей именно ответ имеется в виду. Порядок ответов может меняться.

Comment: @Shamov, поправил

Comment: Хорошо, но лучше ставить прямую ссылку на ответ, которую можно выцепить из кнопки "поделиться" под ответом (я уже сделал поправку).